# Ime keyboard not working for a particular window

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-c++, c++-cli, ime

I have a .net application which is having several dialogs and support many languages. 
Among that, a particular window not supports ime keyboard(Japanese).
on focuzing to any control (textbox) in that window, the IME keyboard gets locked.
The issue is only in Japanese OS and not there in English OS by enabling Japanese IME keyboard.

I have checked the properties of another forms, but all looks same.
I have tried changing the `Localizable` property. But still the issue exists

Looking forward for a suggestion to solve the problem

Comment: I have tried invoking the same from from other forms and in that case it is working. 
But if it is invoked in default way, the ime gets disabled.
Is there any specific reason for this?

Comment: It works on invoking from any UI events. But not from background events.